# LESS nested elements

Tags: css, nested, less

I know that

```
div {
  a {
    ...
  }
}
```

in LESS will stand for

```
div a {
  ...
}
```

in CSS.  The question is what is the LESS code for this:

```
div > a {
  ...
}
```

?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use

```
div {
  > a{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

or

```
div {
  & > a{ /* & represents the current selector parent, so will be replaced with div in this case in the output */
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Both have the same effect and would produce the following as compiled output.

```
div > a {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Note:** You can follow the same approach for the `+` (adjacent sibling combinator) and the `~` (general sibling combinator) also.

Comment: You beat me to it. :p

Comment: @YevgenySimzikov: Nice to know it helped mate. Please mark the answer as accepted when time permits.